# in edit mode the cell is not transparent in mac app

Tags: cocoa, macos

On a button click I am adding a new row to my tableView & reloading the table view .My table has NSTextField Cell  & I am using the below code

```
[tempArray addObject:@""];
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView editColumn:0 row:[tempArray count]-1 withEvent:nil select:YES];
[tableView setNextResponder:self];

-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    [cell setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

    if([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"DataIdentifier"])
    {
        [cell setDrawsBackground:NO];
        [cell setTextColor:[NSColor grayColor]];
        [cell setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:appDelegate.selectedFont size:appDelegate.selectedFontSize]];  // somewhat like 16 on the pad    
    }
}
```

What happens is now in edit mode my cell is not transparent.It has white background.Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the background color of your NSTextFieldCell to be the same as your tableview's background color.

Use the method **setBackgroundColor:**